# Proportional resizing of buttons in UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistackview

I need to layout 5 buttons as in this image: [image: figure 1]

I need them to resize proportionally on different devices.

I have this code in a method which sets up a view with 5 buttons.

```
UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc]init];

// Add buttons to stackView (buttons are initialised)
[stackView addArrangedSubview:_button1];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:_button2];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:_button3];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:_button4];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:_button5];

stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.view addSubview:stackView];

stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
stackView.spacing = 5;

//Layout Constraints for stackView
[stackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = true;
[stackView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = true;

// 80% of screen height should be used for buttons
CGFloat screenHeightAvailableForButtons = 80/100;
// Calculate multiplier for height of the buttons (5 buttons)
CGFloat buttonMultiplier = screenHeightAvailableForButtons /5;
// 25% of screen width should be used for buttons
CGFloat screenWidthMultiplier =  25/100;

[_button1.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier: screenWidthMultiplier].active = true;
[_button1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.heightAnchor multiplier: buttonMultiplier].active = true;

[_button2.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier: screenWidthMultiplier ].active = true;
[_button2.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.heightAnchor multiplier: buttonMultiplier].active = true;

[_button3.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier: screenWidthMultiplier ].active = true;
[_button3.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.heightAnchor multiplier: buttonMultiplier].active = true;

[_button4.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier: screenWidthMultiplier ].active = true;
[_button4.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.heightAnchor multiplier: buttonMultiplier].active = true;

[_button5.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier: screenWidthMultiplier ].active = true;
[_button5.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.heightAnchor multiplier: buttonMultiplier].active = true;
```

This code returns a blank view. Am I using the methods incorrectly?
I can't work out what I am doing wrong. I need this done programmatically in objective c.

thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on "I need them to resize proportionally on different devices.". Like "if stack view height is xxx buttons offset are xx then button height should be xxx" and similarly with the width.

Comment: @BangOperator  I need it to look like it is in the provided image 'on all devices' and I need to do it programmatically not in IB.  So, in landscape mode,   stackView.height = screen.height minus 20points from top and bottom,  button.height = 1/5 of stackView with 5point spacing between each button.  And stackView.width = 1/4 of screen.width and 20points away from left edge, button.width = stackView.width.  Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, you don't need to set the constraints inside the stack view for buttons. Stack view will handle this automatically.

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    stackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    _button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [_button1 setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    _button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [_button2 setTitle:@"Button 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    _button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [_button3 setTitle:@"Button 3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _button3.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];


    _button4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [_button4 setTitle:@"Button 4" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _button4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _button4.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    _button5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [_button5 setTitle:@"Button 5" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _button5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _button5.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    // Add buttons to stackView (buttons are initialised)
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:_button1];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:_button2];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:_button3];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:_button4];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:_button5];

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [self.view addSubview:stackView];

    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentFill;
    stackView.spacing = 5;

    //Layout Constraints for stackView
    [stackView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor].active = true;
    [stackView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor].active = true;
    // 25% of screen width should be used for buttons
    [stackView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier:25.0/100.0].active = true;
    [stackView.layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor].active = true;

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  I learned that I can also use   'constraintEqualToAnchor: constant:'  to further add a 'constant' value to the constraint so as to position the stackView wherever I want on screen! Great stuff ;)

Comment: @DannyHuseyin if this thas answered you question mark it as answered. 